# I Modified my PATH when installing git. What is the default path on Mac?

Tags: osx, path

When I was troubleshooting a git install, I did a few things.

I think that I modified my default path.

```
Echo $path
```

returns

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

I hope I typed that correctly.
That seems wrong. Why would git be included in my top level path ?

I looked in

```
/etc paths
```

And find this in the file

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

I ask because when I type commands, I am now many times getting this error

```
Dyld:DYLD_environmental variables being ignored because main executable 
(/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
```

Is there something that I can look at in when I type

```
$ env
```

The above error seems to be setting up a bunch of roadblocks.

Comment: Having `/usr/local/git/bin` is probably fine. What is in that directory? I suspect that is where Git keeps all the commands (like `git-log`) that implement the `git` subcommands (such as `git log`), rather than cluttering up `/usr/local/bin` where presumably `git` is kept.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have set `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or one of its relatives, and the system is telling you that you can't interfere with `sudo` like that.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X, the PATH environment variable is build with [path_helper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html). This utility reads the contents of the file /etc/paths and the files in the directory /etc/paths.d to build the PATH environment variable.

Initially the /etc/paths.d directory is empty and the content of /etc/paths is

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

In consequence, the default PATH value is

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Please explain how you determined that value? How do we know that's correct?

Comment: I've modified my answer to add more details.